# Python histogram bins

Tags: python, arrays, histogram

I have this histogram:

```
    hist
(array([49, 33, 21, 11, 10,  9,  0,  0,  0,  2]), array([ 0.        ,  0.26274885,  0.52549769,  0.78824654,  1.05099538,
        1.31374423,  1.57649308,  1.83924192,  2.10199077,  2.36473962,
        2.62748846]))
```

which has 10 bins and the number of counts in each bin. I would like to extract the first array, i.e the number counts in each bin **(array([49, 33, 21, 11, 10,  9,  0,  0,  0,  2])** to use for another calculation.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please make an answer for this. Hilarious!

Comment: @srivatsan - added as an answer so that you may upvote. And may I suggest that you go through the official tutorial @ http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `hist[0]`

Read more in the official tutorial

http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Like string indices, list indices start at 0, and lists can be sliced, concatenated and so on:

```
>>> a = ['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]
>>>
>>> a[0]
'spam'
>>> a[3]
1234
>>> a[-2]
100
>>> a[1:-1]
['eggs', 100]
>>> a[:2] + ['bacon', 2*2]
['spam', 'eggs', 'bacon', 4]
>>> 3*a[:3] + ['Boo!']
['spam', 'eggs', 100, 'spam', 'eggs', 100, 'spam', 'eggs', 100, 'Boo!']
```